# How to get most recent and second recent values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table with most recent and 2nd second recent data from Risk Table

Where data in table is as follow:

```
RiskID        RiskName     RiskScore       RiskDate    ItemID      
1             ABC            10          23/10/2013       12            
1             ABC            8           20/12/2013       12 
1             ABC            5           15/01/2014       12
2             BC             9           19/09/2013       12
2             BC             10          17/12/2013       12
2             BC             9           12/01/2014       12
```

Where I am looking for result like below where ItemID should 12 and RiskStatus should be "Open"

```
R_ID   R_Name  Recent_R_Date  Recent_R_Score  Second_R_Date   Second_R_Date  ItemID
1       ABC       15/01/2014      5              20/12/2013       8           12
2       BC        12/01/2014      9             17/12/2013        10          12
```

Looking for prompt reply from SQL gurus

Comment: SELECT * FROM RISKTABLE ORDER BY RiskDate DESC LIMIT 0,2;

Answer (score 6):

This should do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RiskID 
                                   ORDER BY RiskDate DESC)
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT  RiskID AS R_ID,
        RiskName AS R_Name,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN RiskDate END) AS Recent_R_Date,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN RiskScore END) AS Recent_R_Score,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN RiskDate END) AS Second_R_Date,
        MIN(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN RiskScore END) AS Second_R_Score
FROM CTE
GROUP BY RiskID,
         RiskName;
```

[**Here is an sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f6f6/1) with a demo of this. And the results are:

```
╔══════╦════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════╗
║ R_ID ║ R_NAME ║ RECENT_R_DATE ║ RECENT_R_SCORE ║ SECOND_R_DATE ║ SECOND_R_SCORE ║
╠══════╬════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════╣
║    1 ║ ABC    ║ 23/10/2013    ║             10 ║ 20/12/2013    ║              8 ║
║    2 ║ BC     ║ 19/09/2013    ║              9 ║ 17/12/2013    ║             10 ║
╚══════╩════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: Hi Lama, Thanks for your prompt reply, and if can have N number of row for RiskID. and if I have to add few conditions like WHERE    
   ItemID = 12 
   AND
   RiskStatus =  'Open'
GROUP BY RiskID,
         RiskName
 ORDER BY 
        RiskID desc

Comment: You are talking about conditions and columns that aren't on your question. I answered about what you asked. Either you adapt my code to fit your new requirements or modify the question to add them (also, why would you need the `ORDER BY`?, and **where** do you need it)

Comment: Sorry Lamak, earlier i forgot to add these where conditions as we have to pull the risks for itemID =12 and so one and for ORDER, if I want to show these in descending order like most recent Risk first

Comment: Hi Lamak, I just checked result in sqlfiddle which you have sent, but most recent date should be 15/01/2014 for RiskID 1 and 12/01/2014 for RiskID 2

Comment: @user3271821 This was just a problem with the data type I used on the sqlfiddle. Updated it now